# Write to three embedded charts on a worksheet with different information

Tags: excel, vba

Tried my hardest to solve this problem but am stuck on trying to write to three embedded charts in a worksheet.

This is my code

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Function DOGRAPH(GRAPHDATA As Variant, ID As Integer) As Variant

    'MsgBox "DOGRAPH"

'Stop

Dim tNodes As Variant
Dim nNodes As Integer
Dim bmNodes(), ddNodes() As Double
ReDim bmNodes(nNodes), ddNodes(nNodes)
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To nNodes
    bmNodes(i) = tNodes(i) * 1
    ddNodes(i) = bmNodes(i) * i
Next

Dim SF, BM, DD As Chart

    Set SF = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart
    Set BM = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
    Set DD = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Chart
   
    tNodes = GRAPHDATA(10)

    nNodes = UBound(GRAPHDATA(10)) - LBound(GRAPHDATA(10))
    
    With SF

        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.TEXT = "Shear Force Diagram"

        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = tNodes

    End With
    
    Stop
     
    With BM

        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.TEXT = "Bending Moment Diagram"

        **.SeriesCollection(1).Values = bmNodes**
        '.SetSourceData Source:=Range("O69:P81")
    End With
    
    With DD

        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.TEXT = "Deflection Diagram"

        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ddNodes
        '.SetSourceData Source:=Range("O69:P81")
    End With
Stop

End Function
```

The first chart work fine and I get my SF diagram but the routine breaks on the line with bmNodes. I experimented with setting the data to see a range and the charts work but I need to assign an array to the chart.  I think it is to do with the .SeriesCollection(1) statement.

Any suggestions please?

EDIT

I have stripped out the unnecessary code to isolate the problem.  The workbook is this link [www.hemis.co.uk/TEST.xlsm](http://www.hemis.co.uk/TEST.xlsm)

Select the STOP and choose RUN. I have put a stop at the errors.

Comment: Please note that I have an error in my code. The For statement where I calculate the bmNodes and ddNodes, and the Redim should have gone after nNodes calculation.  The problem with writing to the Charts has not altered.

Comment: Can you post a data sample and what you are expecting as result?

Comment: FYI `Dim SF, BM, DD As Chart` only declares `DD` as Chart - the other two are variants.  `Dim SF As Chart, BM As Chart, DD As Chart` would declare all 3 as Chart

Comment: "the routine breaks on the line with bmNodes" - how exactly does it "break" ?  Is there some code you left out?  Eg where does `tNodes` get populated?

Comment: I have declared SF, BM and DD as Chart on seperate lines; no change.  The error message states on the line '.SeriesCollection(1).Values = bmNodes' - Invalid Parameter. tNodes is an array of 3000 points with each value caclulated in a seperate module that is passed to the function within the variable GRAPHDATA. I call the function using DOGRAPH = Application.Run("DOGRAPH", RESULT, ID); RESULT being GRAPHDATA in the function. ID is an integer; in this case 10.

Comment: What type of thing is GRAPHDATA ?  Are you calling this from another application (that would explain the use of `Application.Run` which typically you don't need if you're just working in excel)  Also, it looks like you're filling bmNodes and ddNodes from tNodes *before* you populate tNodes ?

Comment: I have written a sheet that replicates my problem. How do I attach the workbook please? I could put the workbook into a web-link